# JTextField is not working as expected in Netbeans IDE

Tags: java, netbeans

I have one Class named `MainFrem`

```
public class MainFrem extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public MainFrem() {
        initComponents();

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        ok = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        ok.setText("ok");
        ok.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                okActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(74, 74, 74)
                .addComponent(ok)
                .addContainerGap(144, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(62, 62, 62)
                .addComponent(ok)
                .addContainerGap(70, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void okActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
        new SecondClass().setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("Ok button Pressed.");
        new SecondClass().FeelIn.setText("Operation Successful.");

    }                                  

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MainFrem().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton ok;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

And the Second Class is

```
public class SecondClass extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public SecondClass() {
        initComponents();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        FeelIn = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(48, 48, 48)
                .addComponent(FeelIn, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 67, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(62, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                .addComponent(FeelIn, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(53, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new SecondClass().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    public javax.swing.JTextField FeelIn;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

I am using NetBeans IDE and most of the code is generated by the IDE. in the class named `Mainfrem`  I wrote the code below and this is the only code is written in the two class by me.

```
private void okActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
    new SecondClass().setVisible(true);
    System.out.println("Ok button Pressed.");
    new SecondClass().FeelIn.setText("Operation Successful.");

}
```

In the class named `MainFrem` I take a JButton and set the Action Listener like as show above, and in class named `SecondClass` I just add a JTextField named `FeelIn`. I am trying to press the `ok` button in the class`MainFrem` and change the JTextField in the `SecondClass` as `Operation Successful.`. The JTextField in the `SecondClass` is not changing to `Operation Successful` Is there a way to solve the problem.

Comment: Don't you have to `setVisible(true)` the other `SecondClass`?

Comment: I add the JTextField in `SecondClass` from the `pallate` in Netbeans. I am suppose Netbeans does all the work ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `new SecondClass()` both times. I assume that what you want to do is this:

```
private void okActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    SecondClass frame = new SecondClass()                                   
    frame.setVisible(true);
    System.out.println("Ok button Pressed.");
    frame.FeelIn.setText("Operation Successful.");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private void okActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
    new SecondClass().setVisible(true); // An anonymous SecondClass instance
    System.out.println("Ok button Pressed.");
    new SecondClass().FeelIn.setText("Operation Successful."); // Another anonymous instance?

}
```

You are just creating new anonymous instances of SecondClass, that's the problem. Basically, you are just creating instances and throwing them away.